# Block layout pass programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

This is my View Hierarchy:

-RelativeLayout [rootView] (root)

- LinearLayout [menu_holder] (menu fragment layout)
- RelativeLayout [app_holder] (app content layout)

  - Action Bar (custom view to implement ActionBar < 2.1
  - FrameLayout [content_fragment] (layout to load content fragment)
  - FloatingMenu (custom LinearLayout to show a floating widget)

```
<com.example.app.views.widgets.RootLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drag_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white" >

    <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/menu_holder"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:background="@color/red"
       android:orientation="vertical" />

    <com.example.app.views.widgets.AppHolder
    android:id="@+id/app_holder"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/gray" >

    <com.example.app.widgets.ActionBar
        android:id="@+id/action_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_holder"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/action_bar"
        android:background="@drawable/backrepeat" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <com.example.app.widgets.FloatingMenu
        android:id="@+id/floating_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    </com.example.app.views.widgets.AppHolder>
</com.example.app.views.widgets.RootLayout>
```

Now I load both menu_holder & app_holder into the rootView, such that app_holder stays on top. Now when the user presses MENU button, app_holder slides towards right to show the underlying menu fragment on the left, like in the picture below:

[image]

I have used a [scroller](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Scroller.html) inside a runnable to slide app_holder towards right. I also call invalidate() every 16ms on the rootView after offsetting my app_holder.

Its working fine, but problem comes when any content gets loaded in the content_fragment (visibility set or loaded from web), when the menu fragment is visible. The invalidated view (out of bounds) calls requestLayout() and the following layout call resets the app_holder to its initial position. I have implemented lazy loading listviews on my content_fragment, so any update on the listview (notifyDataSetChanged etc.) initiates a relayout call.

How to stop this from occurring ?

Overriding and commenting requestLayout() on all dynamically loaded views on the right will fix the issue, but is there any other proper way ?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question more ?